# Python plot using surface

Tags: python

I have this file : https://pastebin.com/WK6K97jv (columns are respectively x,y,z=f(x,y)).

I would like to plot using matplotlib (pyplot) unfortunately I never have to deal with 3d plot and I've tried to do this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X=np.genfromtxt('./jpdf1/jpdf1.000533048.dat',usecols=(0,))
Y=np.genfromtxt('./jpdf1/jpdf1.000533048.dat',usecols=(1,))
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z=np.genfromtxt('./jpdf1/jpdf1.000533048.dat',usecols=(2,))

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

but interpreter back me this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 431, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1658, in plot_surface
    raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")
ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.
```

Answer (score -1):

check the `Z.shape` whether equal to `X.shape` or `Y.shape`.

```py
Z.shape == X.shape
```

then give your a example.

```py
# import package
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


# generate x and y data
X = np.arange(20) # shape: 20
Y = np.arange(30) # shape:30

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y) # convert x y data shape to new shape

print(X.shape) # (20,30)
print(Y.shape) # (20, 30)

Z= np.cos(X**2 + Y**2) # shape =(20,30)
printt(Z.shape) # (20, 30)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Comment: does this code plot my data?

Comment: may be your should convert your data to `numpy matrix`